# Find P(X>a, X>b)

Tags: probability, order-statistics

What is the meaning of the probability $P(X>a, X>b)$, where X is a non-negative continuous random variable and a,b are two positive constants? Is this same as $P(X>max(a,b))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the same. Comma typically means intersection, i.e. $\cap$.

Comment: Thank you very much